# Is it possible to get the specific type of an OleDbException in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbexception

I try to catch/get the Type of the `OleDbException` to generate the correct error message.

At this moment I'm sure I catch whatever OleDbException, but I want to catch only duplicate value violations to generate the error message.

This is what I do for the moment.

```
ex As OleDb.OleDbException
MessageBox.Show(ex.Errors.Item(1).ToString(), "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
```

The output is like:

> "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UC_MyTable'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.MyTable'. The duplicate key value is
>   (PJO, Peter Johanson)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `.InnerException` property of the exception.

See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) about it.

---

You can also use the `.ErrorCode` property or just use the hash code generated by the message, which will be different for each error message:

```
ex.Message.GetHashCode
```